# DBeaver DB2 variable usage

Tags: string, variables, db2, dbeaver

I'm currently trying to add some dbeaver parameters to my script.

The simple SQL Looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTRACT WHERE CONTRACT_NUMER = :CONTRACTNUMBER;
```

Now, when I run the Statement, dbeaver prompts me for the contract number which I type in. (The column is a varchar) Unfortunately it only works, if I put my Input Parameter in single Apostrophe.
When I just type in the string the following error message appears:

LE123990123 IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.19.49

How do I make this Parameter being treated as a String? DB2 11 is in use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MUST put quote for CHAR and VARCHAR variable.

If you look bottom in `BIND PARAMETERS WINDOWS`, you can read:
"Use Tab to switch. **String values must be quoted**. You can use expression in values"

Comment: No way to ship around this requirement via the SQL Statement? I have tried '':CONTRACTNUMBER'', but this didn't work

Comment: Not that I know